# How to turn slo-mo into time lapse?

Tags: ios, photos, camera

I accidentally chose slo-mo to record a long video instead of time lapse. How can I convert it?

Comment: You'll need a video editor to do that.  Slow motion takes many more frames per second than normal achieving a slowing down of things.  Time lapse takes much fewer frames per second essentially speeding up things.   You need to remove frames between each "still" to acheive this.